# “dass er in Zeiten wie diesen nicht mehr studierte” – why “studierte”?

Tags: verb, subjunctive

I can not understand a test question, can someone explain it to me.

> Frank sagt, dass er in Zeiten wie diesen nicht mehr ... (studieren), wenn er noch einmal jung wäre.

- studiere
- studierte
- stüdiere
- stüdierte

The correct answer is *studierte,* but I don't understand why.

Comment: You'll need the subjunctive (he wouldn't study ... if he were young) which is studierte (or: studieren würde). Never mind that the last two words aren't valid anyway, since there is no very st**ü**dieren.

Comment: Why you don't understand why? (Providing the reason is essential, so that the user that wants to write an answer won't deal with a large scope).

Comment: It’s clear that the test creators intended _studierte_ to be the right answer, but personally, I wouldn’t accept it as right. In my grammar, you can only use _studieren würde_ hier. How old is the test?

Comment: What? Last time I checked subjunctive was still alive and kicking. I don't say _studieren würde_ is not a valid choice, but that's certainly true for _studierte_ as well.

Comment: @Ingmar yes it is, but mostly for those cases where it's *not* identical to the past form. To avoid ambiguity, the infinitive + würde is typically preferred.

Comment: Wouldn't this just be *Präteritum Konjuntiv*? http://www.vocabulix.com/conjugation/studieren.html

I do agree that it's not used very often, however it's definitely not *wrong*.

Comment: @Ingmar: I stand by what I said above: _I_ can’t say so in this past-irrealis-in-indirect-speech.

Comment: Well, I can, and in good conscience at that.

Answer (score 3):

The *Konjunktiv II* of regular verbs is the following:

> **merken**
>
> ich *merkte* / würde merken
>
> du *merktest* / würdest merken
>
> etc.

Now, it's true that the short form is barely used in the modern language, but it's still common in literature. However, German would not be German if there weren't exceptions from that rule. Modal verbs, modal expressions and some very common verbs are preferably used in the short form:

> ich könnte, du wüsstest, er bräuchte, es gäbe, wir müssten, es ließe sich, ihr wäret, Sie nähmen...

The reason for this is probably that for regular verbs the short form is identical with the past form which leads to ambiguity. Irregular verbs take mostly an umlaut in the Konjunktiv form (or at least an *-e* at the end) which makes the meaning clear...

So I wouldn't say, that the given answer *studierte* is not correct - it is correct indeed, but not commonly used.

In your question you haven't specified, if you don't understand *why* the form is *studierte* or *why* we have to use Konjunktiv II. To consider the second possibility as well: it is a condition (an unreal one), not a fact, that's why we should use Konjunktiv II. Compare English:

> Frank says, he **wouldn't study** (...) if he **were** young again.

The form *studiere* would be Konjunktiv I, which is used mostly in passive voice so it would not be appropriate in this case anyway. The last two possible answers don't actually exist.